# C# Mocking Database.ExecuteSqlRaw

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core

I am trying to mock the Database.ExecuteSqlCommand but it prompted me *Unsupported expression* Is there anyway that I can mock the repository to mock *dBContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand*

**Repository.cs**

```
    private readonly Mock<DBContext> _dbContextMock;

    public ShippingBulkRepositoryTest()
    {
        _dbContextMock = new Mock<DBContext>(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DBContext>().Options);
        _repository = new Repository(_dbContextMock.Object);
    }

public async Task deleteAllRecords(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     try
     {
         dBContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM bulk");
         dBContext.SaveChanges();
     } catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex);
     }
}
```

**RepositoryTest**

```
 [Fact]
 public async Task deleteAllRecords_should_call_GetAllSortedByPlateAsync_onto_service()
 {
     //given
     var bulk = _fixture.Build<bulk>()
         .With(x => x.id, 1)
         .With(x => x.type, "bulk")
         .CreateMany(1);
     //_dbContextMock.Setup(x => x.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(It.IsAny<string>()));

     //when
     await _repository.deleteAllRecords(default);

     //then
     _dbContextMock.Verify(x => x.SaveChanges(), Times.Once);
 }
```

**Error**

```
Message: 
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'databaseFacade')
```

Comment: Generally, you only mock interfaces.  ExecuteSqlRaw is an extension (which cannot be mocked).

Comment: As an aside, this code has some really bad practices.  Catching all exceptions (at least it's logged), java style function names, unused parameters, async when there are no await.

Comment: @Neil Thank you for pointing out. Let me work on what you commented.

Comment: You are testing a database here, so use actual database. If you call tests "unit tests" that doesn't mean you should mock everything. Call your tests as you wish, but to have valuable and maintainable tests for the method in the question - test it against actual database or In-memory provider in case it supports raw sql queries.

Comment: @Fabio I am using this boilerplate where the developer mock the repository. Hence, I am trying to follow. https://github.com/lkurzyniec/netcore-boilerplate/blob/master/test/HappyCode.NetCoreBoilerplate.Core.UnitTests/Repositories/EmployeeRepositoryTests.cs

Comment: @rosepalette that's why the code is bad - Boilerplate uses some *very* bad practices and "generic repositories" on top of EF DbContexts are exceptionally bad.

Comment: @rosepalette if you want to test SQL, just create a test database, perhaps using LocalDB. That's what it's for. You **can't** mock a method that executes a SQL query without knowing what the query itself is and how it affects the data. Mocking can get you so far, but what are you really testing once you try to mock SQL queries?

Comment: In fact, at this point EF is meaningless. That `SaveChanges` can easily do 100 INSERTs right after deleting everything too (that's why Boilerplate and generic repositories are so bad). It would be better to use eg Dapper or straight ADO.NET to execute this query with a single call.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The latest versions of EF core allow you to use the [in-memory database provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) to run this kind of integration test.

Comment: I am trying to write a unit test for that, hence mocking that. Is there any other way than using the in-memory database provider?

Comment: No.  One of the main reasons that the in-memory db provider was created, is because so many developers are trying to do what you are doing and failing.   Just use the tools provided.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out what I should do and suggesting the in-memory db. I managed to get it works. Still trying to pick up .netcore. Kudos!

Comment: No, please read what's said about in-memory database here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/.