# How can I test C# EF core DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw() when calling stored procedure?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, stored-procedures

This is a follow up question to this post: [C# Mocking Database.ExecuteSqlRaw](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62674554/10069673)

I have the following call in my code:

```
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("dbo.MyStoredProcedure")
```

Previously I didn't use a stored procedure and was using an InMemoryDatabase for my tests. This worked well until I replaced my code with a stored procedure and called it with `ExecuteSqlRaw`. Now I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Relational-specific methods can only be used when the context is using a relational database provider.

How can I set this up in a test? It would even be enough to just verify that the correct stored procedure is called.

Comment: FWIW I personally feel that this is on the upper end of a waste of time, effort, and money for one stored procedure. writing a test to prove you can return dummy data is not useful at all.  Personally id just double check the code, and move on.

Comment: If you really need to test against a real database. IMHO, create a test fixture, run each test in a transaction & roll them all back. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/sharing-databases

Comment: Apparently you didn't read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/. The in-memory database is mainly for testing EF internals. Don't use it for testing application code.